# How do I compile the Linux kernel with Clang?

Tags: kernel, compiling, compiler

Just out of curiosity, I am interested in compiling the Linux kernel with both the *clang* and *zapcc* compilers; one at a time.

I can't find a guide to follow. Only GCC is getting used to compile the Linux kernel.

How do I compile the Linux kernel with other compilers?

Comment: Uh…didn't you Google the fact that Linux kernel can't be complied with other compilers?

Comment: Uh...not really  : https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OpenMandriva-Clang-Kernel

Comment: I have did both google search, and read the phoronix's site. I think many people have already done what I am asking here, many say they failed, and many say they have successfully compiled Linux with clang!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The kernel build allows you to specify the tools you want to use; for example, to specify the C compiler, set the `CC` and `HOSTCC` variables:

```
make CC=clang HOSTCC=clang
```

The build is only expected to succeed with GCC, but there are people interested in [using Clang instead](https://github.com/ClangBuiltLinux/linux/wiki/Steps-for-compiling-the-kernel-with-Clang), and it is known to work in some circumstances (some Android kernels are built with Clang).

Comment: Actually I am more interested in the zappcc and how well it performs! But because clang is more common and people will be searching for it, I just asked about clang!

Comment: Yes, that’s what I thought; I mentioned Clang because there are others working on that. I’m not aware of a similar effort for zapcc ;-).

Comment: Building with the Intel compiler has been [possible](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-for-linux-kernel-building) for some time although not supported. I actually had an entire Gentoo build done years ago with the Intel compiler when I had a lot more free time than I have now.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Stephen Kitt's answer. It's possible to compile the Linux kernel with Clang. But you need Clang v9.0.

### Setting Up

If you are using Arch Linux, there's a nice way to clang v9.0 without compiling yourself:

```
# Enable the testing repository (if not already enabled):
echo -e "[testing]\nInclude = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist" | sudo tee -a /etc/pacman.conf

# Update the database and install clang, llvm, llvm-libs
sudo pacman -Sy testing/clang testing/llvm testing/llvm-libs

# Check if you have clang-9:
clang --version
```

*Note: In future, if the extra repository adds clang version 9, you can install that*.

After you got clang-9.0, Download the kernel of your choice from [here](https://www.kernel.org).

Simply compile the kernel with the aliased make:

```
alias make="make CC=clang HOSTCC=clang -j `nproc`"
```

Proceed with the installation procedure.

After all done, reboot your system. And then type:

```
cat /proc/version
```

The above code will show you the kernel version with some extra details.
For example, my /proc/version file looks like this:

```
Linux version 5.4.0-rc1 (sourav@archlinux-pc) (clang version 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)) #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Oct 6 18:02:41 IST 2019
```

### Performance

I don't know if this is a real placebo in effect or not, but it's working a bit faster than the GCC compiled version. I have also compiled games like Xonotic with clang9 and zapcc where clang-9 outperforms both zapcc-7.0 and gcc 9.1.0.

### Conclusion

I think it's a good idea to compile the Kernel with clang 9. But zapcc can't do that right now. According to both zapcc version 7.0 and clang version 8.0.1 (which I have tried):

```
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
Compiler lacks asm-goto support.
```

Hope this helps!